# Website loads different content

Tags: wordpress, browser, web

This is the [website](http://www.charmaynemakeup.com/)

This looks perfect in Asian Region. But when my client sees the site from USA, the website loads some random chinese products and chinese characters.

I checked for malware and found none. How to resolve this.
Please see the screen shot attached:
[image: the chinese content screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to make sure that the user doesn't have the page cached. Make sure that they try refreshing the page a few times.

Second, I would try installing the Wordfence plugin which will compare your plugin and themes against the actual deployments.

Comment: Your second option really worked out. Sometimes we tend to overlook basics. Highly appreciate your help. Thanks.